# strange behavior with two similar cycles

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I'm using C++11, why is the first case working while the second needs `auto&&` ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Obj {
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Obj> vobj(10);
    for (auto& e : vobj)       // Works
        std::cout << "Yes";

    std::vector<bool> v(10, false);
    for (auto& e : v)          // Fails
        e = true;
}
```

Comment: This probably have to do with [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) being a very special case.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have marked this as a duplicate of the one you linked. Sorry for the dupe